# How can i add new theme for code editor in android studio for ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, android-studio, intellij-idea

i have this website for android studio themes , and there is help how to apply theme to android studio through add ICS files to colors folder , where i can find this folder in ubuntu ??

http://www.androidstudiothemes.com/content/help

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about ics files, but for xml files, add them in

```
~/.AndroidStudio3.3/config/colors
```